# Redis vs Mysql engine type memory

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, redis

I would like to know if anyone has had experience with these search engines, I'm at about 2500 records consisting of id and name (id-> 5 ....... name-> city, state) in a table, that is read-only and almost never change, if I select mysql, I think to use: select id, name from cities where name like '%text%' and name like '%othertext%'; ... one like, for each word, or maybe Redis, what option is more suitable for this case? is an autocomplete for a website and exist cities whit long names and several words per name.

Answer (score 5):

For autocomplete lists (with a startswith or wildcard search), Redis on its own isn't your best bet. I recently added some functionality to Redis to accomplish this (well, the startswith bit). See the pull request [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/1634).

If you want to jump on the NoSQL wagon, an integrated solution like ElasticSearch or SOLR is worth looking into. They use Redis as a backend, and provide sophisticated tokenisation and natural language detection (Lucene and the likes).

Using an object mapper, like (python examples here) Josiah Carlsons's [rom](https://github.com/josiahcarlson/rom/tree/master/rom) or Luca Sbardella's [stdnet](https://github.com/lsbardel/python-stdnet), is also an option. They store the data in such a way that simple queries can be executed in Redis using automated Lua scripting.

If you prefer to stick with SQL, there is nothing wrong with using a relational database like MySql or Postgres. Especially with such a small amount of rows.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: Thanks for the answer TW, new options to analyze :)